# Not able to run build.gradle in eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, build

I'm trying to build java project and I've installed Buildship Gradle Integration into Eclipse, after that I've created Gradle project, but I don't have option to run build.gragle as Gradle Build.

this is what I have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing  Run As, you can use 
Gradle > Refresh Gradle project 
to resolve your dependencies etc.